# Three.js what does computeCentroids do?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was making my own custom geometry with three.js (using typescript). Something was wrong with it, the object appeared all dark with Lambert material. I checked the three.js source code to see if I forgot to do something when creating the geometry. I saw these two lines appear at the end of the constructor of nearly every geometry class:

```
this.computeCentroids();
this.computeFaceNormals();
```

Adding the computeFaceNormals solved my problem. I remember something about normals having to do with lighting (so that makes sense).

But I don't know what the computeCentroids does, and where/why those centroids are needed. Can someone explain? Also do I need to call that function? What can happen if I don't?

Comment: computeCentroids() no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`computeCentroids` calculates the centroid of each *triangle* in a mesh, not the center of the mesh itself.

Probably the easiest way to see their purpose is to search for `.centroid` in the three.js source code.  AFAICS, they are not used for much apart from lighting, but then only if you're using `CanvasRenderer`.